# create border around icon depending on variable

Tags: php, html, css

[What i currently have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49u8G.png)

[what im trying to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBJHq.png)

I need it when i throw for example 2 and 3 it goes down 2 and marks it from left to right using black borders, and then it goes 3 to the right and mark from top to bottem using black borders, at the point they cross i need it to be a red border.

````
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="form.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
  <?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $dice1 = mt_rand(1,6);
  $dice2 = mt_rand(1,6);

  echo "<table class='table'>";
  for ($i=0; $i < 6 ; $i++) {
    echo "<tr>";
    for ($j=0; $j < 6 ; $j++) {
      echo "<td> <img class='icon cell color".mt_rand(1,4)."' src='img/icon".mt_rand(1,4).".svg ' </td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
  }
  echo "</table>";
  echo "<img class='dice1' src='img/dice".$dice1.".gif'>";
  echo "<img class='dice2' src='img/dice".$dice2.".gif'>";
}
   ?>
   <form method="get" action="/php1/eindopdracht/cal.php">
    <button type="submit" class="button1">renew</button>
</form>
   <form method="POST">
     <button type='submit' class='button2' name='submit' value='submit'>throw</button>
   </form>
</div>
 </body>
 </html>```
````

Comment: Please post the code where you have marked the border around images that didn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title></title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="form.css">
 </head>
 <body>
   <div class="wrapper">
   <?php
   if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   $dice1 = mt_rand(1,6);
   $dice2 = mt_rand(1,6);

   function chooseBorder($i,$j,$dice1,$dice2) {
       $class = "";
       if ($dice1 == $i && $dice2 == $j) {
           $class = "border-red";
           return $class;
       }

       if ($dice1 == $i || $dice2 == $j) {
           $class = "border-black";
           return $class;
       }
       return $class;
   }
   for ($i=1; $i < 7; $i++) {
       echo "<tr>";
       for ($j=1; $j < 7 ; $j++) {
           $class = chooseBorder($i,$j,$dice1,$dice2);
           echo "<td> <img class='icon cell color".mt_rand(1,4). " " . $class . "' src='img/icon".mt_rand(1,4).".svg ' </td>";
       }
       echo "</tr>";
   }
echo "</table>";
echo "<img class='dice1' src='img/dice".$dice1.".gif'>";
echo "<img class='dice2' src='img/dice".$dice2.".gif'>";

}
    ?>
    <form method="get" action="/php1/eindopdracht/cal.php">
     <button type="submit" class="button1">renew</button>
 </form>
    <form method="POST">
      <button type='submit' class='button2' name='submit' value='submit'>throw</button>
    </form>
</div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if dice1 value is equal to $i you can add a certain class that makes the color black. Same if dice2 value is equal to $i. If then dice1 is equal to $i and dice2 value is equal to $j choose a different class to make the border red.

```
function chooseBorder($i,$j,$dice1,$dice2) {
    $class = "";
    if ($dice1 == $i && $dice2 == $j) {
        $class = "border-red";
        return $class;
    }

    if ($dice1 == $i || $dice2 == $j) {
        $class = "border-black";
        return $class;
    }

    return $class;
}


for ($i=0; $i < 6 ; $i++) {
    echo "<tr>";
    for ($j=0; $j < 6 ; $j++) {
        $class = chooseBorder($i,$j,$dice1,$dice2);
        echo "<td> <img class='icon cell color".mt_rand(1,4). " " . $class . "' src='img/icon".mt_rand(1,4).".svg ' </td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, i currently have the following code: https://github.com/T3chGames/Php-error/commit/edfe10c771142570f82e76dadf841255aa692313
but i get this error: 
"Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function chooseBorder() in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP1\eindopdracht\cal.php:19 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP1\eindopdracht\cal.php on line 19"

Comment: also i added these 2 classes in my css:
.border-black {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
}


.border-red {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
}

Comment: Sorry for that, you need to move the function above from where it was called!

Comment: Im sorry im new to programming can you explain it? i can't seem to fix it on my own.

Comment: I will change my post, one second

Comment: Glad to be of help. ping me up if you need anything more